# unable to access docker port in windows

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have written script in dockerfile to run my Angular Project.It will create container.When I am running my container I am unable to access that host and port in my browser.

It says connection refused. 
(i am using windows machine)Running docker with Toolbox.

My container :

```
> 81471a6fbd35  0fa791d373d8 "npm start" 8080/tcp,
> 0.0.0.0:8080->8089/tcp
```

And when i am inspecting my container it is giving IP address as
Network settings:-

```
> "NetworkSettings": {
>             "Bridge": "",
>             "SandboxID": "1668451fef162c41627c58f4bea5946d07dec3d8f329217d1b6c8847ef60fb3b",
>             "HairpinMode": false,
>             "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
>             "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
>             "Ports": {
>                 "8080/tcp": null,
>                 "8089/tcp": [
>                     {
>                         "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
>                         "HostPort": "8080"
>                     }
>                 ]
>             },
```

Comment: How are you trying to access the container?  Can you share your `docker run` command?  Might you have typoed `-p 8080:8089` expecting both ports to be 8080?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,yes i have tried that one also then it is saying that port is already assigned to another container

Comment: Add the docker command to run the container and which port you are using for accessing the application in browser.

Comment: try a different port (not 8080)